# When I try to add .jpg to the end of a cell's text in calc, using concatenate, multiple spaces are inserted

Tags: openoffice-calc

I have in column B a list of product names (I.e. AFFALL1) and in column C, I need to have the same text, but with a .jpg on the end.

I have tried to use concatenate as follows:

In cell C2:

=concatenate(B2;".jpg")

which partially works, except that it keeps inserting multiple spaces, whereas I need to it have no spaces.

It looks like this:
A4499FA             .jpg

When I need it to look like:
A4499FA.jpg

I have no idea where these extra spaces are coming from. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try =concatenate(TRIM(B2), ".jpg");

Comment: Do your cells in column B have a trailing space?

Answer (score 0):

[@Barbara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2588368/barbara-laird) has the right idea but OpenOffice uses semicolon as the parameter separator, so:

```
=TRIM(B2)&".jpg"
```